# How to calculate the current balance of every account number using php

Tags: php

i have an array like below.The **from** field is account number  of  the person  the money is, the second field  is  the amount  of  money,
and the third   field **to** is  the account number  of  the person  the money   is  to.  Then how can i calculate   the current balance of  every account number.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [from] => 314
        [amount] => $470.21
        [to] => 275
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [from] => 12
        [amount] => $1,788.98
        [to] => 149
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [from] => 316
        [amount] => $2,949.53
        [to] => 417
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [from] => 5
        [amount] => $2,193.48
        [to] => 454
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [from] => 198
        [amount] => $1,402.76
        [to] => 371
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [from] => 82
        [amount] => $1,212.14
        [to] => 420
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [from] => 222
        [amount] => $1,167.72
        [to] => 396
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [from] => 348
        [amount] => $4,024.42
        [to] => 399
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [from] => 474
        [amount] => $1,216.86
        [to] => 60
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [from] => 449
        [amount] => $974.59
        [to] => 422
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [from] => 415
        [amount] => $232.12
        [to] => 351
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [from] => 164
        [amount] => $353.19
        [to] => 42
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [from] => 321
        [amount] => $4,202.13
        [to] => 377
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [from] => 99
        [amount] => $1,178.71
        [to] => 51
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [from] => 251
        [amount] => $3,015.86
        [to] => 262
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [from] => 374
        [amount] => $2,014.48
        [to] => 299
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [from] => 351
        [amount] => $2,807.71
        [to] => 302
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [from] => 286
        [amount] => $2,516.63
        [to] => 166
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [from] => 110
        [amount] => $464.08
        [to] => 385
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [from] => 171
        [amount] => $1,623.41
        [to] => 452
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [from] => 293
        [amount] => $727.26
        [to] => 208
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [from] => 373
        [amount] => $2,200.46
        [to] => 499
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [from] => 194
        [amount] => $1,393.01
        [to] => 258
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [from] => 315
        [amount] => $764.34
        [to] => 487
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [from] => 199
        [amount] => $586.14
        [to] => 48
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [from] => 67
        [amount] => $402.24
        [to] => 59
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [from] => 481
        [amount] => $6,551.75
        [to] => 400
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [from] => 154
        [amount] => $1,076.45
        [to] => 193
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [from] => 431
        [amount] => $577.47
        [to] => 196
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [from] => 408
        [amount] => $385.03
        [to] => 153
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [from] => 240
        [amount] => $532.56
        [to] => 92
    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [from] => 195
        [amount] => $60.00
        [to] => 361
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [from] => 425
        [amount] => $438.85
        [to] => 417
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [from] => 309
        [amount] => $2,222.94
        [to] => 131
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [from] => 366
        [amount] => $732.07
        [to] => 76
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [from] => 492
        [amount] => $891.88
        [to] => 342
    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [from] => 384
        [amount] => $1,936.74
        [to] => 414
    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [from] => 83
        [amount] => $270.87
        [to] => 427
    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [from] => 43
        [amount] => $1,100.84
        [to] => 202
    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [from] => 428
        [amount] => $1,825.57
        [to] => 387
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [from] => 238
        [amount] => $1,059.79
        [to] => 381
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [from] => 426
        [amount] => $416.23
        [to] => 97
    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [from] => 190
        [amount] => $7,057.28
        [to] => 238
    )

[43] => Array
    (
        [from] => 229
        [amount] => $722.97
        [to] => 159
    )

[44] => Array
    (
        [from] => 129
        [amount] => $785.86
        [to] => 303
    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [from] => 44
        [amount] => $2,961.07
        [to] => 105
    )

[46] => Array
    (
        [from] => 306
        [amount] => $893.92
        [to] => 178
    )
)
```

Comment: Where is the exact problem? What have you tried?

Comment: i am unable to make a logic of this.

Comment: have a (maybe existing) target array sorted by with 'account number' as key; then loop through these transactions and add/substract values in target array.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a $balance array indexed by account number. Then traverse the original array in a for loop.

At each element, you can subtract the 'amount' from the $balance indexed by 'from' and add the 'amount' to the balance indexed by 'to'.

Answer (score 0):

okay i did it myself and here is the solution

```
    function checkBalance($array){
      $accounts = [];
      if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)){
       foreach($array as $value){
        $amount = preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $value['amount']);
        $account_from = $value['from'];
        $account_to = $value['to'];
        $transaction_amount = $amount;
         if (isset($accounts[$account_from])){
            $accounts[$account_from] -= $transaction_amount;
         }
        else{
            $accounts[$account_from] = (0 - $transaction_amount);
        }
        if (isset($accounts[$account_to])){
            $accounts[$account_to] += $transaction_amount;
          }
        else{
            $accounts[$account_to] = $transaction_amount;
          }
      } 
  }
  return $accounts;
}

print_r(checkBalance($array));
```

and yeah thanks for everyone who replied :)